# How do I stop the second onclick function from happening while the first function is executing?

Tags: javascript

I'm currently working on a validation feature. If the form fails to validate, it won't be able to submit, hence, I need to figure out a way to prevent the submitFilloutform() from happening.

```js
<button 
  id="submit" 
  name="submit"
  type="submit"
  class="btn btn-warning"
  style="float: right;"
  onclick="validateForm(), submitFilloutform()"
>Submit</button>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: [Use client-side validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation), and keep the button disabled until all the fields are filled correctly, and then when the button is clicked call `submitFilloutForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I came back to this as someone upvoted it (thanks). One consideration to add it that inline JS may be a bad idea in the case that you want to lock down potential for cross-site-scripting attacks. Part of the defence of that is CSP headers and one strong contender to set is a rule that bans all inline JS. So, if you plan to use CSP you might want to move the JS below into an onclick listener for id=submit in a separate JS file.

Original answer.

onClick is executed like a function, so can include JS logic. Such as...

```
<button 
  id="submit" 
  name="submit" 
  type="submit"  
  class="btn btn-warning" 
  style="float: right;" 
  onclick="if (validateForm()){ submitFilloutform();}"
>
Submit
</button>
```

This assumed that validateForm() returns a boolean value, of course.

Comment: A good solution; although we're not sure whether or not `validateForm` returns a boolean value.

Comment: Thank You So much, I didn't know you could include JS code inside a html element!

Answer (score 1):

Why not invoke the second function at the end block inside the first function?

```
<button 
  id="submit"
  name="submit"
  type="submit"
  class="btn btn-warning"
  style="float: right;"
  onclick="validateForm()"
>Submit</button>

function validateForm() {
  // xxx
  submitFilloutform()
}

function submitFilloutform() {
  // xxx
}
```

Comment: Maybe not ideal as assumes all  successful validation leads to submission? And in such a case why not put the submission code into the validation function.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat Agree with you,it depends on what's the OP want to do